# Добавление столбца в DataFrame с вычислением значений для него

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Ниже приведенный скрипт, который подсчитывает частоту появление лоторейных шаров в играх, сортирует результат по убыванию по частоте и разбивает полученную стастику на категории по 3 шара. 
Вопрос - как правильно добавить столбец в DataFrame и расчитать для него  значение не используя цикл? Результат должен соотвествовать результату работы ниже приведенного скрипта.

Исходный код

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from collections import Counter
import json
from random import randint
from itertools import chain
import operator
from functools import reduce

def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--draws', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():

    lastNDraws = 20

    args = ArgParser()
    draws = pd.read_csv(args['draws'], sep=';',header=0, index_col='draw_id')

    bc = (draws.stack().value_counts()).to_frame()

    print(bc) 

    bc['category'] = 0
    bc.columns = (['count','category'])    

    for i in range(0, len(bc)):
        bc.values[i][1] = i // 3

    print(bc)


    print('The End')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

1) Результат работы скрипта

```
    count  category
32     28         0
6      27         0
27     26         0
1      25         1
22     24         1
13     24         1
4      23         2
30     23         2
9      23         2
23     23         3
12     23         3
15     23         3
29     22         4
8      22         4
28     21         4
16     21         5
25     21         5
11     21         5
7      20         6
18     20         6
33     20         6
19     19         7
21     19         7
24     19         7
26     19         8
17     18         8
35     18         8
5      18         9
14     17         9
31     16         9
3      16        10
2      15        10
10     14        10
36     12        11
34     11        11
20     10        11
```

Исходные данные.

```
draw_id;ball1;ball2;ball3;ball4;ball5;ball6;ball7
1;9;11;17;29;30;33;36
2;5;6;9;11;15;33;28
3;4;5;10;14;20;30;8
4;4;21;22;25;26;36;6
5;1;11;13;17;24;29;36
6;2;17;22;24;27;30;1
7;4;15;26;28;29;35;34
8;12;22;24;26;31;33;2
9;6;9;16;24;33;34;17
10;3;8;12;19;27;31;1
11;4;5;7;9;14;20;25
12;9;20;32;33;35;36;22
13;16;19;23;25;29;32;12
14;6;10;11;17;33;35;15
15;1;5;16;19;22;28;33
16;3;6;7;8;16;29;12
17;1;3;10;19;24;32;23
18;9;25;27;29;33;35;22
19;7;13;17;18;21;34;6
20;7;14;18;20;27;33;28
21;1;3;5;8;22;23;25
22;4;5;13;19;28;34;11
23;3;24;26;32;35;36;14
24;2;7;18;22;30;32;4
25;5;22;28;30;31;33;3
26;1;4;6;28;31;32;13
27;7;10;15;18;23;30;8
28;6;10;12;16;18;19;4
29;9;12;16;21;23;27;3
30;6;15;18;19;25;29;2
31;4;7;22;28;29;30;15
32;3;7;14;18;33;35;29
33;4;14;21;23;28;29;30
34;2;5;9;21;26;27;20
35;1;3;9;11;13;17;27
36;11;13;15;28;32;35;18
37;3;11;16;21;28;35;15
38;1;2;12;13;14;15;6
39;5;10;13;16;18;21;20
40;1;4;18;23;32;36;7
41;6;9;13;17;18;35;23
42;11;13;19;23;24;27;12
43;2;3;8;14;32;35;25
44;1;5;12;14;21;25;9
45;2;4;15;25;28;31;9
46;19;21;23;26;30;35;2
47;11;16;22;23;24;30;8
48;8;9;11;27;30;35;32
49;1;15;22;26;31;32;25
50;3;5;8;12;16;21;7
51;7;8;13;21;22;32;30
52;1;4;8;14;27;30;12
53;2;16;20;22;27;30;21
54;1;5;16;25;27;36;22
55;4;26;28;30;32;33;6
56;5;10;13;18;24;27;29
57;1;4;5;8;22;25;28
58;3;11;24;27;29;34;17
59;1;2;6;9;14;23;32
60;5;10;12;15;24;33;22
61;5;12;15;23;24;32;18
62;2;5;11;13;25;28;10
63;8;13;18;19;27;31;12
64;7;9;11;23;32;34;22
65;2;4;7;15;27;30;26
66;4;12;15;16;17;19;11
67;6;7;9;12;17;19;27
68;12;17;25;27;32;33;36
69;6;19;20;26;27;35;21
70;6;15;21;32;34;35;1
71;4;7;9;10;14;23;26
72;6;21;26;30;31;32;28
73;3;8;13;22;29;31;12
74;6;8;13;15;27;34;5
75;8;13;24;29;31;33;6
76;6;14;17;23;26;32;21
77;4;9;15;16;23;32;13
78;1;8;13;23;27;33;24
79;1;13;16;26;29;32;6
80;9;12;16;22;24;35;32
81;8;9;18;19;23;28;20
82;1;6;7;20;28;29;32
83;8;17;22;25;26;31;11
84;3;11;18;24;26;29;1
85;10;11;13;21;27;30;6
86;2;13;23;25;30;35;29
87;14;16;17;25;29;30;4
88;7;8;12;22;25;31;16
89;16;23;24;27;32;33;19
90;6;16;18;25;27;28;7
91;13;15;17;19;24;32;6
92;1;12;15;19;27;34;36
93;3;6;7;9;18;33;31
94;6;11;12;14;21;29;23
95;8;11;14;15;29;36;22
96;1;9;14;25;30;32;26
97;4;10;25;31;35;36;17
98;9;16;27;32;35;36;23
99;10;21;28;29;31;34;17
100;1;12;13;24;26;33;22
101;2;4;15;18;19;30;8
102;4;7;10;19;30;33;34
103;1;11;15;18;28;31;26
```

Comment: На Stackoverflow не задавать несколько вопросов сразу - это best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создать новый столбец - просто присвойте фрейму `список` или `1D numpy array`  длина которого соответствует длине DataFrame'а :

```
df['new_column_name'] = [...]
```

Код:

```
bc = (draws.stack().value_counts()).to_frame(name='count')
bc['category'] = np.arange(len(bc)) // 3
```

результат:

```
In [54]: bc
Out[54]:
    count  category
32     28         0
6      27         0
27     26         0
22     24         1
13     24         1
1      24         1
9      23         2
..    ...       ...
3      16         9
31     15        10
2      15        10
10     13        10
36     12        11
20     10        11
34     10        11

[36 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: np.arange(len(bc)) // 3 - а я искал функцию или аттрибут в DataFrame, чтобы вычислить номер строки - типа row_number(). Про использования numpy  arange я бы сам врятли быстро догодался. Вот что значит практика :)